# antd Modal open and closing issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have some react component, which have a Modal component of popular antd lib.
This component having some prop - let's call it `isOpen` prop and sending it down to andt Modal component. Like that:

```
const SomeCustomComponent = (props) => <Modal visible={props.isOpen} ...
```

I'm managing state of that isOpen prop outside of that component.

```
const [dialogIsOpen, setDialogState] = useState(false);

<SomeCustomComponent 
    isOpen={dialogIsOpen}
    onCloseDialog={() => setDialogState(false)}...

<button onClick={() => setDialogState(true)}...
```

So, all is simple.

And I've faced an issue, where after modal is opened or closes, it, for some reason, jumps to top of the body no matter what trigger I'm using onClick on

I dont want document jump to top when modal props changed.
How to fix that issue?

Comment: What do you mean by `document jump to top`? what document do you mention to? It's better if you provide an image of UI to demonstrate the issue

Comment: I think he means it scrolls to top. Can you create a snippet or edit mine. https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-kalam-e7h9e?file=/src/App.js . I don't see the issue though. The modal stays disregarding the scrollbar

Comment: This is not antd modal issue, check other elements styles.